# Input ignored on first try

Tags: python, speech-recognition

i have this problem with Speech Recognition. When the user gave the input, it ignore it and ask again.
Here's the code

```
def getVoice():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening: ")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        aud = r.listen(source)
    try:
        query = r.recognize_google(aud, language= "en-US")
        print(f"You said: {query}\n")

         
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print(f"Please {name}, try again.\n")
        query = None
    return query
```

Comment: try printing the exception: "except sr.UnknownValueError as e: print(f"Error: {e}")" and add the error message to the question.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Listening: ")
    text = r.listen(source)
    try:
        recognised_text = r.recognize_google(text)
        print(recognised_text)
        
    except sr.UnknownValueError as uve:
        print(f"unknownvalueerror occurred: {uve}")
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print(f"Requesterror occured: {e}")
```